# Why is my '#id' transformed into 'data-drupal-selector'?

Tags: forms, 8

In a custom form I (try to) write, I have this element at the end:

```
$form['referent'] = array(
    '#id' => 'breferentdistrib',
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#default_value' => ($bReferentDistrib) ? "Y" : "N"
);
```

'breferentdistrib' being used in javascript this way:
`var breferentdistrib = document.getElementById("breferentdistrib").value;`

Unfortunately, I get this in the rendered HTML:
`<input type="hidden" value="N" name="referent" data-drupal-selector="breferentdistrib">`

No 'Id' and 'data-drupal-selector' instead.
Of course, my `getElementById("breferentdistrib")` is not working...
Any idea?

Comment: It's intentional: https://www.drupal.org/node/2503277

Comment: OK, I get this. By the way, it says _there is an automatically added additional attribute: data-drupal-selector corresponding to the element id before randomization._ In my case, **data-drupal-selector** replaces the **id**. So, how can I get the element in my javascript?

Comment: There's an example on that link, just use an attribute selector (jQuery supports them). If you'd rather an ID, I'm sure you can force an attribute using `$form['referent']['#attributes']['id'] = 'foo';`

Comment: Indeed, it works! Though I don't understand why `$form['referent'] = array(
    '#id' => 'breferentdistrib',
    '#type' => 'hidden',`did not...

Answer (score 5):

It's intentional as @clive says. You can select it using jQuery or CSS of the this way:

```
div[data-drupal-selector=your-selector-id]
```

If you want to use a id you can declare like this:

```
$form['referent']['#attributes']['id'] = 'foo';
```